# SharePoint Modern List Gallery view change the font color of a " Person or Group" field

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need to change the font of all the fields on a Gallery view to white. I did that for all but the "Person or Group" field. is it possible to change the font color of the field?

Comment: Can anybody help? how to change the font color of a "Person or Group"field using JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the steps in the image and paste the JSON code into step 5：

[image]

Using the following JSON code:

```
{  
  "elmType": "div",  
  "txtContent": "@currentField.title",  
  "style": {  
    "color":  "#FFFFFF",  
    "padding-left": "14px"
  }
}
```

The effect is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm new to SharePont JSON, so I have a hard time knowing where to add the code snippet. could you please check my code below and let me know where to add?

Comment: I'd be happy to, I've updated the answer with detailed steps, please check it out.

Comment: Has my method helped you? If you have any questions, you can contact me at any time, and I will help you solve it.

Comment: Hello Sir, thanks for your help, but unfortunately I'm not able to open the image.

Comment: 1.open the SharePoint Online list, expand the Person column 2.select the column settings3.and click on the "Format this column" option.
4.In the format columns properties pane, select or choose advanced mode.
5.paste the JSON code.Click save.

Comment: Did my answer help you?If you need any help, let me know.It's been a while, We will look forward to your response. Stay safe and stay healthy.

Comment: Thank you Sir. it works in list view but doesn't in Gallery view.  I will accept your answer anyway. thanks for help!